# How to tell which element number i'm clicking on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 6  elements.. How can I know which one in the dom have I clicked on? Meaning.. I want to know that I click on tag  #3 as it is the 3rd (or 4th if you count 0) in the dom..

I was thinking of just assigning an ID to each  tag and that id would contain a number designating which  is being clicked.. but there must be a cleaner way...

hope this is clear enough - sorry i'm tired.

Answer (score 2):

just figured it out.. jquery has an .index() feature.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure that this is what you are looking for:
http://api.jquery.com/index/#example-0

Comment: thanks, i luckily figured it out on my own.. but thanks for helping!